# Find function which contains two points

Tags: calculus, functions

A certain function  contains points $(-3,5)$  and $(5,2)$. We are asked to find  this function,of course this will be simplest if we consider slope form equation

$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$

but could we find for general form of equation? for example quadratic? cubic?

Comment: 18 minutes. $ $

Comment: Note that a *function* $f$ does not *contain* any point $(a,b)$. Rather, $f(a)=b$, or equivalently, $(a,b)$ belongs to the *graph* of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a quadratic equation $y= ax^2 + bx + c$, then you need at least three points to completely determine the quadratic; plugging in just two points gives you two equations in three unknowns:
$$\begin{align*}
5 &= a(-3)^2 + b(-3) + c\\
2 &= a(5)^2 + b(2) + c.
\end{align*}$$
This gives you the equations
$$\begin{align*}
9a -3 b + c &= 5\\
25a + 2b + c &= 2.
\end{align*}$$
There are infinitely many solutions to these equations. Similarly, with a cubic, you need 4 points to completely determine it; with just two, you get two equations in four unknowns, after setting it up as $y=ax^3 + bx^2 + cx+ d$.

When you have $n$ different points, then the method of [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolation) will produce a polynomial of degree $n-1$ whose graph goes through the given points.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, but there would be many solutions. For a quadratic, you start with the general form

$$y=ax^2+bx+c.$$

Then substitute the $x$, $y$ values given by the points.

$$
\eqalign{
5&=9a-3b+c \cr
2&= 25a+5b +c\cr  
}
$$

Solve this for $a,b$, and $c$ (There will be infintley many solutions. To get the solution, give $c$ a value, then solve for $a$ and $b$)